# Unity3D Raycast not destroying gameobject every time

Tags: unity-game-engine, destroy, raycasting

I am working on a Minecraft like game and trying to get block deletion to work properly. I have a function that returns the proper coordinates of the block and then calls DestroyBlock (below) which casts 6 rays in each direction of the face of a cube and is supposed to destroy any quad it encounters. I then have another function that is called after the block is destroyed that then updates the surrounding blocks and renders the appropriate faces. My problem is that this DestroyBlock function doesn't always work. As you can see in the images on the first click, everything works properly and the correct faces are destroyed and then rendered, but when I do the second click, it only destroys one face of the new block...
[image: Before Any Clicks]

[image: After clicking on the corner block]

[image: Results of clicking on the now exposed dirt block face]

```
void DestroyBlocks(int x, int y, int z) {


    Vector3 origin = new Vector3(x, y, z);

    Ray Up = new Ray(origin + Vector3.up, Vector3.down);
    Ray Down = new Ray(origin + Vector3.down, Vector3.up);
    Ray North = new Ray(origin + Vector3.forward, Vector3.back);
    Ray East = new Ray(origin+ Vector3.right, Vector3.left);
    Ray South = new Ray(origin + Vector3.back, Vector3.forward);
    Ray West = new Ray(origin + Vector3.left, Vector3.right);

    RaycastHit markedQuad;

    if(Physics.Raycast(Up, out markedQuad, 1f)) {
        Destroy(markedQuad.transform.gameObject);
        Debug.Log("Destroyed Up");
    }

    if(Physics.Raycast(Down, out markedQuad, 1f)) {
        Destroy(markedQuad.transform.gameObject);
        Debug.Log("Destroyed Down");
    }

    if(Physics.Raycast(North, out markedQuad, 1f)) {
        Destroy(markedQuad.transform.gameObject);
        Debug.Log("Destroyed North");
    }

    if(Physics.Raycast(East, out markedQuad, 1f)) {
        Destroy(markedQuad.transform.gameObject);
        Debug.Log("Destroyed East");
    }

    if(Physics.Raycast(South, out markedQuad, 1f)) {
        Destroy(markedQuad.transform.gameObject);
        Debug.Log("Destroyed South");
    }

    if(Physics.Raycast(West, out markedQuad, 1f)) {
        Destroy(markedQuad.transform.gameObject);
        Debug.Log("Destroyed West");
    }


}
```

And I know that the raycast is hitting the quads because of the debug messages but for some reason it is not actually destroying all the sides when it hits them. Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How long are the edges of a quad? 1 unit? To check if the rays hits the correct quads, you could rename the corresponding gameObjects before you remove them. For example, remove them 30 seconds later by using the time parameter of `Destroy`. In that way you could easily identify the objects in the inspector.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem. When I was updating the adjacent blocks next to the one I clicked, I was rerendering the faces of that adjacent block without first checking to see if a quad already existed there, effectively instantiating two faces at the exact same position. Which is why the raycast and destroy was working, only there were just two quads there so it only appeared it didn't. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Can't see any images and don't really take why it isn't work after first interaction but I'm curious:

1: Why are you controlling each face instead of cube/block itself?

2: I'm thinking in mine craft right now because you mentioned it and I would approach creating an Destroyable interface for blocks to call on trigger or collision with any "destruction tool" or something...

Maybe if you provide more information on your approach and reasons to go your way schould become easier to help...